# Squealing sound coming from driver side on 99 park ave

Tags: noise, buick, park-avenue

I have a 99 Buick Park Avenue. When my car is warmed up (no noise the first 15min of driving or idling) it starts to make a squealing noise, something like a belt noise, but it isn't the belt. The noise is coming from the flywheel area between the oil pan and the flywheel. I've used WD-40, spraying the area between the flywheel and oil pan, then the noise will cease briefly then start back up after (it seems) the WD-40 wore out due to friction. I have ideas but putting them together to figure out what to fix. Different mechanics tell a different diagnosis: one is expensive and the other is doable. Could it be the bearings in the motor? Thank you to anyone that could help.

Comment: I do not believe it would be the bearings in the motor. Spraying WD-40 into the area you are suggesting would have absolutely zero effect on bearing noise. I'm not sure what might be causing the noise, though. Very strange ... maybe you got a rat in there? J/K!

Comment: Yes I find it strange to but I have to do something because the longer the car is driven the louder it gets. Now there is a seal ring that goes around the crankshaft rod that connects to the flywheel. But the oil pan will have to be takin off for it be visible. I get the same kind of answer all the time ( it's wierd). It sounds like metal on metal fiction

Comment: IIRC, the Park Ave is a front wheel drive car powered by a 3800 (super charged??) engine? I'm wondering where you are actually "squirting" the WD-40 to make *any* noise stop. And if WD-40 will do it for a short time, if you squirt some 10w30 in the same place, will it squelch the noise for longer? Unfortunately, I'd need to be present at your vehicle to help you diagnose further. I think your best bet would be to take it to a mechanic you trust and have them diagnose it for you, even if that takes pulling everything apart.

Comment: Its a 3800 front wheel drive V6 (no supercharger).. I wish I could upload a photo but I don't think I can. I will come back with more info if I can thank you

Comment: The exact same thing is happening to me. It starts 15 mins after driving and gets worse as I go. I thought it was something in water pump like a pullie I also just got belt changed so thought it might be that. Also used Wd40 with no help. Ever get a good answer?? I think I localaized sound to fly wheel

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, to my way of thinking, this could be the bearings in the engine. There is absolutely no way you could get any type of penetrating oil into the bearing area of the engine using any type of spray means. These areas are sealed against outside contamination by means of a seal and oil pressure (meaning, if the seal starts to fail, you'd see oil coming *out* so the dirt or other debris doesn't come in).

I'm wondering if the problem is with the torque converter and not the engine? Again, not a real answer, and not something which would be solved (even briefly) with a squirt of WD-40.

What I'm thinking it could possibly be is that the starter is not disengaging properly after starting. You said the noise starts a period of time after the engine is started. If the starter has gotten to a point where it is hot enough, it might start making noise at that point and continue to get louder as time goes on. This is a real stretch, but seams feasible.

I'm afraid without further explanation, there's not much more in the way of an answer we can provide for you.